# Neo4j : Random combinations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to conduct a chess competition for two groups of people. I have to pick a member from each group randomly and conduct the game. Based on the no.of wins of each group, I will decide which group is more talented.

Lets say, Group1 and Group2. Group1 contains 40 people and, Group2 contains 30 people. Now, I have to pick two people, each from one group and conduct a game.

```
Game1 : P1G1----vs----P4G2
Game2 : P23G1----vs----P1G2
Game3 : P12G1----vs----P15G2
....
....
....
Game30: P36G1----vsP30G2
```

How can I get these kind of random combinations using neo4j. Basically, How can I avoid cartesian products for theis UseCase.

Random Selection (by @Micheal Hunger)

```
MATCH (n) WITH count(*) as total
WITH [_ IN range(1,10000) | toInt(rand()*total)] as ids
MATCH (per) WHERE id(per) IN ids AND emp:Group1
RETURN per
```

How can I get the random combinations from each group??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[APOC Procedures](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases) just updated with some [collection functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) that may help (make sure you get the correct APOC version for your Neo4j version)

This requires at least Neo4j 3.1.x and a recent version of APOC.

See apoc.coll.randomItem() and apoc.coll.randomItems().

There are several ways to use these to address your question, depending on factors such as if all players have to participate in at least one game, but here's one example:

If you don't need every player to participate in a game, you just need 30 games total, you can use a combination of these functions to get your matchup.

```
MATCH (g1:Group1)
WITH COLLECT(g1) as g1
MATCH (g2:Group2)
WITH g1, COLLECT(g2) as g2
UNWIND apoc.coll.randomItems(g1, 30) as group1
WITH group1, apoc.coll.randomItem(g2) as group2
RETURN group1, group2
```

Comment: Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, '?', '!', '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR or AS (line 5, column 29 (offset: 136))
"UNWIND apoc.coll.randomItems(g1,30) as group1"

Comment: Made a change to perform the random item function call a line earlier. See if that works. Though technically this should execute fine. Make sure you have APOC procedures installed (and use the correct version for your corresponding Neo4j version)

Comment: I dont see apoc.coll.randomItems() in the list given by calling dbms.procedures(). Apoc version is apoc-3.1.2.5.jar

Comment: Check `CALL dbms.functions()`.

Comment: Invalid input 'b': expected 'r/R' or 'e/E' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
"dbms.functions()"
  ^

Comment: There is no procedure with the name `dbms.functions` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed. (For .. CALL dbms.functions())

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you using? If it doesn't recognize functions, then it's likely some 3.0.x version, and won't be able to make APOC functions calls.

Comment: Yeah. Its 3.0.4 version

Comment: If that case, if you can't update to a 3.1 Neo4j version, you'll have to pick a different answer, this answer requires at least 3.1.x and a recent version of APOC.

Comment: Hoo.. Okk. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of people in groups is small (for example, up to 1000), then it is possible to sort by random and limit:

```
MATCH (A:Group1),(B:Group2)
WHERE A <> B
RETURN A, B 
       ORDER BY RAND() 
       LIMIT 30
```